# Multi-tenant App Does Not Recognise Routes from Mapped Domain

Tags: php, laravel, multi-tenant

I've run into a strange problem while working on my multi-tenant application. My application (`my.app`)  allows users to create their own subdomain (`tenant.my.app`) and serve it white labeled under their own domain (`support.customer.com`) ; which is mapped via CNAME to `tenant.my.app`.

My application works very well for all routes on `tenant.my.app`. However, when I map the domain and type `support.customer.com`, my application shows 404. I have checked that the request actually hits my application and I can do a `dd($request->getHost())`. However, I cannot get any route like `support.customer.com/123` to load.

Here's how I've tested in my routes.php

```
Route::get('/123', function() {
    dd("Hello");
});
```

Surprisingly, on my local environment which runs `valet`, I can link any domain like `customer.test` and get everything to work as expected.

What could be going wrong with this?

PS:
FWIW, I have the following in my session.php, to make way for the incoming domain requests. Not sure how safe this is and whether this is contributing to the error. I've tried hard-coding the value to the test domain; but no use.

```
'domain' = $_server['http_host'],
```

Comment: Are you using any multi-tenant if you are please state it.
Have you tried running `php artisan route: list` , or have you `artisan optimize: clear` 
Are you using Laravel subdomain routes?

Comment: Yes, have tried it. But it doesnt' help.

Comment: Did you hit `Route::get('/', function() {
    dd("Hello");
});`

Do you have any middleware that could be redirecting?

Comment: yes, this could be the issue.
'domain' = $_server['http_host'], ` 'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN'),`  . also, do you have this middleware running \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Laravel Subdomain Routing? did you register it?

```
Route::domain('{account}.customer.com')->group(function () {
    Route::get('user/{id}', function (string $account, string $id) {
        // ...
    });
});
```

Also, to ensure your subdomain routes are reachable, you should register subdomain routes before registering root domain routes. This will prevent root domain routes from overwriting subdomain routes with the same URI path.

Comment: Subdomain approach was obviously my first choice. However, it's not required; since I am mapping customer domains to my application. 

I am simply checking for the incoming request and adding the domain information to the routes; which works for subdomains on my application; but fails when a customer domain is mapped using CNAME.